# Mock Autofac.IComponentContext with unit tests c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofac, nsubstitute

I am trying to mock `IComponentContext` with NSubstitute as below:

```
[TestClass()]
public class SyncRepositoryFactoryTests
{
    private IComponentContext _container;
    private SyncRepositoryFactory _factory;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _container = Substitute.For<IComponentContext>();
        _factory = new SyncRepositoryFactory(_container);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Get_SyncRepositoryOfITestEntity_Success()
    {
        var repository = Substitute.For<IRepository<TestEntity>>();
        _container.Resolve<IRepository<TestEntity>>().Returns(repository);

        var result = _factory.Get<ITestEntity>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.IsTrue(result is ISyncRepository<ITestEntity>);
    }

    public interface ITestEntity 
    {
    }

    public class TestEntity : ITestEntity
    {
    }
}
```

but I get an exception:

```
    ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 
        'Hvb.eMarketAdvisor.Repository.SharePoint.IRepository`1[[Hvb.eMarketAdvisor.
        Repository.SharePoint.Tests.Units.SyncRepositoryFactoryTests+TestEntity, 
        Hvb.eMarketAdvisor.Repository.SharePoint.Tests.Units, 
    Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' has not been registered. 

    To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service,
    check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional()
    method to resolve an optional dependency.
```

As I try to create a mock why does `IComponentContext` try to resolve dependency?

Comment: What is the point of mocking `IComponentContext` ? What are you trying to test here?

Comment: I am testing here the logic of factory Get() method in full isolation. But the question is general about mocking IComponentContext for any other purpose.

Comment: How is `Get` method implemented? If it just calls resolve, you don't get anything useful from your test.

Comment: The question is "As I try to create a mock why IComponentContext try to resolve dependency?", not what my test is doing, because the test throws exception before reaching method code to be tested.

Comment: @Leszek Yes, but without seeing how `Get` is implemented, it's difficult to give you an answer. Clearly, the stubbed `Resolve` method on the component context isn't being called, and your unit test is hitting a live container. As for how that's happening, we'd need to see how `SyncRepositoryFactory` uses the component context it's passed.

Comment: if you are mocking your container in your tests then something is wrong. your code shouldn't depend on your container and should be testable in isolation from the container. I'd review your design decisions.

Comment: Error is hit in this line:  _container.Resolve<IRepository<TestEntity>>().Returns(repository); 
The class constructor:

        public SyncRepositoryFactory(IComponentContext container)
        {
            if (container == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            }
            _container = container;
        }

Comment: Put a debug breakpoint on that line and inspect the true type of `_container`. Your code must be creating a real `ComponentContext` instance instead of mocking it.

Answer (score 4):

Because `Resolve<>()` is an extension method and so you're just executing the extension method, not mocking its call. You need to mock the call that the extension method calls.

As the commenters above have said, if you're mocking your DI container, something is wrong with your design.

Answer (score 3):

Old question but if anyone comes here looking for how to it do for whatever your reason is, as of Autofac 4.9.2 the following should work for you.  Obviously if you need more logic you can get fancy with the substitutions.

```
public interface ICalculate
{
    bool ProcessData();
}

public class ReallyCoolCalculate : ICalculate
{
    public bool ProcessData()
    {
        return 2 + (2 * 3) == 8;
    }
}

public void GetCalculateFromAutoFac()
{
    var calculate = new ReallyCoolCalculate();

    var componentContext = Substitute.For<IComponentContext>();
    var componentRegistration = Substitute.For<IComponentRegistration>();
    componentContext.ComponentRegistry.TryGetRegistration(Arg.Any<Service>(), out Arg.Any<IComponentRegistration>()).Returns(true);
    componentContext.ResolveComponent(Arg.Any<IComponentRegistration>(), Arg.Any<IEnumerable<Parameter>>()).Returns(calculate);

    var calculateFromAutoFac = componentContext.Resolve<ICalculate>();
```

}